# style @android:attr/activityOpenEnterAnimation not found

Tags: android, android-attributes

Here's my IDE and gradle plugin version:

AndroidStudio:`3.1.4`

classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`

In my project,I have a main module and a sub module.

In my sub module, I have a `values.xml` like following:

```
<style name="OmActivityAnim">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_right</item>
</style>

<style name="OmActivityAnim2">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
</style>
```

but when I run my `Main module` I just got 
AAPT: error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityOpenEnterAnimation' not found.

following errors

```
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityOpenEnterAnimation' not found.    
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityOpenExitAnimation' not found. 
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityCloseEnterAnimation' not found.   
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityCloseExitAnimation' not found.    
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityOpenEnterAnimation' not found.    
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityOpenExitAnimation' not found. 
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityCloseEnterAnimation' not found.   
error: style attribute '@android:attr/activityCloseExitAnimation' not found.
```

But, why my `android:activityOpenEnterAnimation` changes to `'@android:attr/activityOpenEnterAnimation'`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add '@' before 'android'.Because '@android' is the exact annotation to write the theme reference to another resource.

Edit your code from

```
<style name="OmActivityAnim">
<item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_right</item>
<item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_left</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_left</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_right</item>
</style>

<style name="OmActivityAnim2">
<item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="OmActivityAnim">
<item name="@android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_right</item>
<item name="@android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_left</item>
<item name="@android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_from_left</item>
<item name="@android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_slide_to_right</item>
</style>

<style name="OmActivityAnim2">
<item name="@android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="@android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="@android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/om_base_show_dialog_anim</item>
<item name="@android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/om_base_dismiss_dialog_anim</item>
</style>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks,but it does't work. Actually the submodule is referenced by other proj and it works,And I can not modify the submodule cause others has no problem but I got,which means the problem is mine